# Confusion in understanding Boolean logic

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic

I am trying to follow a tutorial on boolean logic given here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-python/

There is an example which I cannot follow and would appreciate help.

**Example**:

```
a = (1 == True)
b = (1 == False)
c = True + 3
d = False + 7
print("a is", a)
print("b is", b)
print("c is ",c)
```

**Confusion**: Why is `b` assigned 1 as False? Why is `1` again being re-used to denote False? Shouldn't 0 be the value corresponding to False? If I change the line to `b = (0 == False)` then  `print("b is", b)` displays `b is True` How come?

Comment: In different languages there are values which are defined as Truthy and values which are defined as Falsy. In your particular case (and language), 1 is defined as a Truthy value (meaning True) and 0 is defined as a False value(meaning false). Therefore, 1 == False is False.

Comment: `1==False` _is_ False, so b is set to False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python (and some other languages), `1` equals `True` and `0` equals `False`. Hence, since `True != False`, the statement `1 == False` (which can be restated as `True == False`) itself has the truth value `False` and assigning `(1 == False)` to `b` amounts to the same as `b = False`. In turn, assigning `(0 == False)` to `b` results in `True`, because `0 == False` is the same as `False == False`, which is `True`.

Comment: Note that this pertains to Python (and perhaps to a named class of languages I'm unaware of). In Boolean logic, `1` is not equal to True, nor to False, nor is Green equal to Friendly. Another computer language might evaluate `1 == True` as False, or as a syntax error, without violating Boolean logic.

Comment: @Beta You're right, of course. I updated my post on this point.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just to clarify, if `y = (2 == False)`
`z = (3 == True)`
`r = (1 == False)` then what should I expect the output?

Comment: @Sm1 The output would be `False` for all three.

Answer (score 0):

The phrases in format of `(1 == True)` or `(1 == False)` are actually comparison statements and they evaluate to `True` or `False` which are assigned to the variables on the left.

In Python, objects defined to be `False` include:

> constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
>
> zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
>
> empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

Refer [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bool) of Python doc for more details.